# How do I create a Microsoft Teams Meeting externally from a ServiceNow Instance?

Tags: microsoft-teams, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I've been given the requirement of having a UI action in ServiceNow that can schedule and create meetings within the Microsoft Teams Platform.

Has anyone been able to achieve this or have a good understanding of how much dev work would be involved?

I'm assuming it would be an API call from ServiceNow to Microsoft Teams but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at [Create online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Note: These APIs are still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

Teams uses outlook and exchange calendars/meetings. So you should create a meeting for outlook, documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations